# Estimating the largest transversal Lyapunov exponent using orbit separation – what did I do wrong?

Tags: stability-theory, nonlinear-dynamics, synchronization

I am trying to extract the MSF (master stability function) for a network of chaotic Rössler systems. I am letting one subsystem to evolve to its chaotic attractor; then we have a trajectory $s(t)$. After the transient has died out, I take several random points on the attractor, e.g. ${s(t=100), s(t=200), ...}$ and insert $(x_s,y_s,z_s)$ into the variational equation:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\delta_i(t) = [\mathrm{D}F(s)-\alpha \mathrm{D}H(s)] \delta_i(t)
$$

I then let this evolve for a rather large time and calculate its largest Lyapunov exponent via the orbit-separation method. At the end, I take the mean value to represent the largest Lyapunov exponent of the variational dynamics. So far, did I do right?

However, the negative region of the MSF does not agree with the ones I see in different papers. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that while I wouldn’t consider this question off-topic here, I [proposed a Stack Exchange site for complex systems](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/114901/complex-systems), which would probably be a better home for such questions as it provides more visibility to the diverse community of people working on complex systems. Please consider participating in that proposal and post your question as an example question there.

Comment: You may be interested in [this software I wrote](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.09886) that almost completely automatises the numerical estimation of transversal Lyapunov exponents (using tangent vectors instead of orbit separation).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thank you for the proposal and the editing, I found this stack exchange (mathematics) the closest subject to my question ...  therefore I asked it here ... should I delete this topic now ?

Comment: *should I delete this topic now ?* – No, not at all. As I said: “I wouldn’t consider this question off-topic here”.

Answer (score 0):

You do not talk much about this step, so I cannot be sure, but you seem to be missing the transformations that allow to separate directions tangential and transversal to the synchronisation manifold. If you do not do this, you should always get a positive Lyapunov exponent due to the chaoticity of the Rössler system.